# CSS is breaking in the iPad after updating IOS 13.4 Beta version

Tags: css, ios, typescript, cordova, ngx-bootstrap

We developed an iPad application, and 
After upgrading 13.4 we saw that few CSS is breaking like ngx bootstrap modal, radio button Textbox

We are using

"typescript": "~3.5.3" 
"Cordova": "^9.0.0", 
"cordova-ios": "^5.0.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^4.1.1",

Below IOS 13.4 version everything works fine, 
 we strongly believe its not a code issue because we have tested the app in iPad **Safari browser** with same IOS 13.4 beta version everything works perfectly but breaks only when we install the app (dmg file)

We are still not sure why this is breaking the code. is this  because of Cordova or ngxBootstrap or any other issue

Does anyone facing any similar issue? can we expect a fix from IOS itself after IOS 13.4 public release?

Any little information about this would be helpful.

Comment: please share safari link

Comment: @this.girish safari link is just a local, you cant run in your iPad

Comment: You need to do some workaround then, without piece of code its nearly impossible to suggest you to do make certain changes.

Comment: I understand, but I am still not sure where the problem is. If the problem is with our code then, how the same code it is working perfectly in the IOS 13.3.1 version but not in 13.4 beta version which released recently.

Comment: clean/clear cache and check, also check your viewport

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/796 comments mention issue resolved in beta 3